# Show object based on property with random value

Tags: javascript

I would like to show an object based on a random value of the property "id". The random value has to be between 1 and the amount of objects in the array. Currently I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var card = [
    {
        name: "string 1"
        , value: "this"
        , other: "that"
        , id: 1
    }
    , {
        name: "string 2"
        , value: "this"
        , other: "that"
        , id: 2
    }
];
    var obj = card.filter(function (obj) {
    var length = card.length();
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) + 1
    return obj.name === random;
})[0];
console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: `length` is not a method but property...

Comment: The first element of a JavaScript array is at position **0**, not 1.

Comment: If you're only interested in the first match, don't use `.filter()`, use `.find()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to compare the `.name` instead of the `.id`? Seems they're coordinated.

Comment: So how do I calculate the length of an array with objects?

Comment: also will never get those strings to match your variable `random`

Comment: That's a mistake. I changed it to obj.id, but it still doesn't work. The console give also a few errors like "card.length is not a function".

Comment: The id is irrelevant ... just get a random index as in the duplicate linked above. The resultant  item would then have a random id

Comment: Why don't you just pick a random object from the array instead of a random id?

Comment: @FrederikDelaet: As noted above, it should be `.length`, not `.length()`.

Comment: How do I get a random object out of the array?

Comment: Go to duplicate link at top of your question